# D3: Animate circle along border of country on spinning globe

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

My problem is simple to explain but I am having real trouble implementing a solution. I am trying to animate a circle along a path on a D3 map. The twist here is that I would like to use one of Mike Bostock's spinny globes (i.e. 3D map).

In time, I would like to add other paths to the globe and to use these for my animations. For now, I would simply like to animate the circles along the border of Russia (i.e. along the path of the Russia polygon coordinates)

I have built a jsfiddle to get traction on this and you can see all my code. Unfortunately I cannot get it to work, and am hoping you can help me out. My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/xqmevpjg/7/

I think my key difficulty is (a) actually referencing the Russia path, and I think I am not getting it right at the moment, and (b) making sure that the interpolation is calculated properly (i.e. that the animation is dynamically linked to the globe, and not just 'layered on top'). The code that is supposed to do that is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var path = d3.select("path#Russia"),
  startPoint = pathStartPoint(path);

  marker.attr("r", 7)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + startPoint + ")");

  transition();

  //Get path start point for placing marker
  function pathStartPoint(path) {
    var d = path.attr("d"),
    dsplitted = d.split(" ");
    return dsplitted[1].split(",");
  }

  function transition() {
    marker.transition()
        .duration(7500)
        .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
        .each("end", transition);// infinite loop
  }

  function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    return function(i) {
      return function(t) {
        var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";//Move marker
      }
    }
  }
```

I'd be hugely grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, one way to select the path is to add an id to id :

```
d3.json("http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/world-countries.json", function(collection) {
  feature = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features)
    .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", clip)
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.properties.name; }) ;
```

and then select the path like that :

```
var path = d3.select("#Russia").node()
```

Then you can select the first point with :

```
path.getPointAtLength(0)
```

See this updated fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/xqmevpjg/11/